# how to crawl all href on zomato?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

i am trying to crawl into zomato to get info of the restaurants in istanbul. so, i am trying to get all the hrefs in search result pages. however, i am only getting the first search result of every page.

```
import scrapy
from ..items import ZomatodataItem

class ZomatoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'zomato'
    allowed_domains = ["zomato.com"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.zomato.com/istanbul/restaurants?page=1'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        all_css = response.css('.search_left_featured')
        all_product = all_css.css('a::attr(href)').get()

        yield scrapy.Request(all_product, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

        max_page_number = 6
        for i in range(1, max_page_number):
            url_next = 'https://www.zomato.com/istanbul/restaurants?page=' + str(i)+''
            yield scrapy.Request(url_next, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        items = ZomatodataItem()

        items['name'] = response.css('.diBDma::text').extract()
        items['genre'] = response.css('.gQXqL::text').extract_first()
        items['tags'] = response.css('.cunMUz::text').extract()
        items['address'] = response.css('.clKRrC::text').extract()
        items['phone_number'] = response.css('.kKemRh::text').extract()

        yield items
```

Answer (score 1):

Makes sense that you only get 1 result - 'all_product' will only contain 1 item. If you want to get the full list, you'll have to update it to this:

```
all_products = all_css.css('a::attr(href)').getall()
```

Now you can loop through the links and get the detailed information like this:

```
for product in all_products:
  yield scrapy.Request(product, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)
```